# ASP.NET 5 / MVC 6, How to use session in class library?

Tags: session, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-1.0, class-library

With .NET 4.6.1 I wanna use Sessionstate in a class library, something like :

```
    public static void SetUserId()
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Session["userId"] = 1;
    }
```

but when I call this method it throws an exception "An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request." > "NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object."
I have a reference to system.Web in my class library. In .NET 4 I can do this safe. But it is a problem in .NET 4.6.1. 
How can I solve this?
Thanks

Comment: This should be a good sign that you are doing it wrong, if you need to access the session ID in such way in a class library

Comment: what is wrong? I have a project from .NET 4.0 and it works well. the problem raises when I migrated to .NET 4.6.1

Comment: Well perhaps inspect the actual exception?

Comment: it's a NullReferenceException exception. HttpContext is null but why?

Comment: @AliBorjian: Don't call infrastructure from your class libraries, use abstractions. Just the idea of directly accessing the HttpContext (which isn't available anymore like this outside of the controller, just by injecting IHttpContextAccessor) should tell you, that you use a complete wrong approach

Comment: Directly accessing HttpContext is available in .NET 4.0 , It's a problem with 4.6.1 (MVC 6). How do you access your states in a class library?

Comment: The .NET framework has nothing to do with this.

Answer (score 1):

This is `null` by default, the concept driving **ASP.NET Core 1.0** is pluggable middleware. You need to explicitly opt-in for session.

You need to ensure that both the `Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory` and `Microsoft.AspNet.Session` dependencies exists in the `project.json`. Then in your 
`Startup.cs` add the following:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // Add framework services.
    services.AddMvc();
    services.AddCaching();
    services.AddSession(options => { 
            options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30); 
            options.CookieName = ".MyApplication";
        });
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    app.UseSession();

    // Removed for brevity...
}
```

Detailed article [here](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/270/sessions-in-asp-net-core-1-0). That should be all you need to do.

**Update**

Avoid attempting to use `HttpContext.Current` outside of the web application. This is intended only within the context of the HTTP request / response pipeline. It is preferred to utilize abstractions to achieve the desired interactions you're looking for.

I would need you to share more source code in order to provide an explicit example.

Comment: Session Stae is available in my ASP.NET Application, My problem is inside the class library.  I access sessions in my ASP.NET Application but not in the class library. In .net 4.0 I didn't have such problem. the exception arises when I migrated to .NET 4.6.1. By the way we don't have any startup.cs inside a class library.

Comment: for Update : How do u access your application state in the class library? instead of sessions maybe we use : wep service? shared memory ? database? Note that I don't want to pass parameters from web app to class library as it is not a fluent code.

Comment: Ali - you abstract the heck out of it. If you need the current session in your class library, then pass it as an argument in the constructor.

Comment: Actually, `HttpContext.Current` shouldn't be used even in web applications anymore. It's a static class, hard to test/mock. The new ASP.NET Core is fully driven by IoC and dependency injection. If one needs HttpContext outside of the inherited controller (i.e. poco controllers or services), one injects `IHttpContextAccessor`